# Convert a .jar file into a .cod file using bb-ant

Tags: blackberry, ant, jar

I'm working on a Blackberry application (JDE 4.6.1) on a Windows system. I need to convert a .jar file in a .cod file using bb-ant-tools. Does anybody know how to do it? I'm using:

> ```
> <target name="convert">
>         <rapc import="source.jar" destdir="${path}\bin\" output="source"  jdehome="${testing.jde}" generatesourcelist="true">
>          <src> 
>             <fileset file="${testing_path}\lib\microlog.jar">
>              </fileset>
>          </src>
>         </rapc>  
> </target>
> ```

Unfortunately I receive back this error message:

> [rapc] C:\test\source.jar: error! Duplicate definition for 'net.sfender.AbstarctFileAppender' found in....

which could be the problem?

thanks

Comment: I assume you meant that you want to convert a .jar file *into* a .cod file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target is converting microlog.jar, with source.jar as a reference jar. Is that what you want?

If you want to convert source.jar, include it in the src element, and remove it from import.