# Convert cod to jar in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Hii Folks,

I've a cod file to run on blackberry device but i want to convert it into jar. Is it possible to do so??Is their any script or is their any tool exist for that kindly suggest me regarding this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[Blackberry\] Convert a .jar file into a .cod file using bb-ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094043/blackberry-convert-a-jar-file-into-a-cod-file-using-bb-ant)

Comment: @Swati that is exactly the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no." There's a tool [Coddec](http://drbolsen.wordpress.com/2008/07/14/coddec-released/) that is supposed to help with this, but it's pretty flakey. I've never gotten it to work. It's also rather old and even if you could get it to work, it probably would only be good for cod files generated by older versions of the tools.

Comment: Okk .Thnx for your response...I've also seen this but this is not working.